# Does the H2 SCRIPT command work like a snapshot?

Tags: database, behavior, h2

H2 database has a command called SCRIPT to backup content and/or structure. It can be performed while the database is running.

My question is: Does SCRIPT work like a snapshot? Does it only take statement and database content up until the SCRIPT command is issued? Or does it try to take additional statements performed by other processes into account while SCRIPT is being executed?

**EDIT**

To clarify the question, there are two ambiguities about the usage of SCRIPT:

- Does SCRIPT guarantee transactional safety/consistency while performed when database is running?
- Is SCRIPT producing a smaller output than BACKUP?

I am asking this question to know whether I should interrupt some queries while performing a backup of my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SCRIPT` command locks each table (for reading) at the beginning. So the resulting SQL script is transactionally consistent. Please note other operations are blocked until the operation is complete (even when using the multi-threaded option).

> Is SCRIPT producing a smaller output than BACKUP?

It depends on the data. Usually the SQL script is a bit smaller, but not much. It is quite a lot smaller when using compression. The main advantage of the script is that you have a human readable backup which is not tied that much to the software (the file format of H2 might change, but SQL will not).

Answer (score 1):

"The [recommended way to backup a database](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore) is to create a compressed SQL script file. This can be done using the [`Script`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Script.html) tool." Unfortunately, the only way to ensure transactional consistency while the database is in use is to use the SQL command [`BACKUP`](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#backup), which also copies the transaction log.

Comment: "this is not recommended while the database is in use." > In the link you provide, this comment is related to the idea of copying files, not using SCRIPT.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller is the author and a regular contributor to SO. He's helped me more than once, and I would defer to him on this.

Comment: Yes, I know, that's why I am not closing the question lol. I am reading the doc and the Javadoc. If I understand it well, there are 2 tools: the backup tool and the SQL backup command. It seems that the backup tool is safe if and only if the database is closed. On the other side, it seems the SQL backup command can be executed safely while the database is up. The last question would be, what's the point of allowing to run SCRIPT while database is running if it is not transaction safe !?!!

Comment: A `SCRIPT` backup appears to be more space efficient, which would allow more frequent backups during quiet times. I'd still want a periodic `BACKUP`.

Comment: @Thomas Mueller I have updated my question to clarify it. Trashgod mentioned you might help. Thanks.